# Difference between snmpd and net-snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am new to SNMP. As far as I know snmpd is a Linux daemon for SNMP which acts as SNMP agent. We can install it from the package snmpd. Now net-snmp also provides a SNMP agent.

Does net-snmp provide snmpd daemon as its agent, if so then what is the use in installing net-snmp if one already has installed snmpd (provided one needs the SNMP agent only)?

Answer (score 3):

The **net-snmp** suite comes in 3 Linux packages.

`net-snmp` package is the one which has the `snmpd` component mentioned in question.

The 3 Linux packages are:

- **net-snmp** (the **snmpd** **agent** and snmptrapd daemons, documentation, etc)
- **net-snmp-utils** (various utilities e.g. for interrogating SNMP agents, sending traps, etc )
- **net-snmp-libs** (runtime libraries)

See http://www.net-snmp.org/ for full details.

More detailed descriptions for each (package descriptions & file contents) follows:

**net-snmp**

```
yum info net-snmp 
Summary     : A collection of SNMP protocol tools and libraries
Description : SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) is a protocol used for
            : network management. The NET-SNMP project includes various SNMP tools:
            : an extensible agent, an SNMP library, tools for requesting or setting
            : information from SNMP agents, tools for generating and handling SNMP
            : traps and a version of the netstat command which uses SNMP. This
            : package contains the snmpd and snmptrapd daemons, documentation, etc.
            : 
            : You will probably also want to install the net-snmp-utils package,
            : which contains NET-SNMP utilities.
```

Files involved:

```
repoquery --list net-snmp
/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmpd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmptrapd
/etc/snmp
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf
/etc/sysconfig/snmpd
/etc/sysconfig/snmptrapd
/usr/bin/net-snmp-create-v3-user
/usr/bin/snmpconf
/usr/sbin/snmpd
/usr/sbin/snmptrapd
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/AGENT.txt
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/ChangeLog.trimmed
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/EXAMPLE.conf
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/PORTING
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/README
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/README.agent-mibs
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/README.agentx
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/README.krb5
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/README.mib2c
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/README.snmpv3
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/README.thread
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/TODO
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/ipf-mod.pl
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-5.5/passtest
/usr/share/man/man1/net-snmp-create-v3-user.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpconf.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/snmp_config.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/snmpd.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/snmpd.examples.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/snmpd.internal.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/snmptrapd.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/variables.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/snmpd.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/snmptrapd.8.gz
/usr/share/snmp
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmp-data
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmp-data/authopts
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmp-data/debugging
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmp-data/mibs
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmp-data/output
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmp-data/snmpconf-config
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/acl
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/basic_setup
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/extending
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/monitor
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/operation
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/snmpconf-config
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/system
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/trapsinks
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmptrapd-data
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmptrapd-data/authentication
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmptrapd-data/formatting
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmptrapd-data/logging
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmptrapd-data/runtime
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmptrapd-data/snmpconf-config
/usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmptrapd-data/traphandle
/var/run/net-snmp
```

**net-snmp-utils**

```
Summary     : Network management utilities using SNMP, from the NET-SNMP project
Description : The net-snmp-utils package contains various utilities for use with the
            : NET-SNMP network management project.
            : 
            : Install this package if you need utilities for managing your network
            : using the SNMP protocol. You will also need to install the net-snmp
            : package.
```

Files involved:

```
repoquery --list net-snmp-utils
/usr/bin/encode_keychange
/usr/bin/snmpbulkget
/usr/bin/snmpbulkwalk
/usr/bin/snmpdelta
/usr/bin/snmpdf
/usr/bin/snmpget
/usr/bin/snmpgetnext
/usr/bin/snmpinform
/usr/bin/snmpnetstat
/usr/bin/snmpset
/usr/bin/snmpstatus
/usr/bin/snmptable
/usr/bin/snmptest
/usr/bin/snmptranslate
/usr/bin/snmptrap
/usr/bin/snmpusm
/usr/bin/snmpvacm
/usr/bin/snmpwalk
/usr/share/man/man1/encode_keychange.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpbulkget.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpbulkwalk.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpcmd.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpconf.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpdelta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpdf.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpget.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpgetnext.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpinform.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpnetstat.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpset.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpstatus.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmptable.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmptest.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmptranslate.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmptrap.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpusm.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpvacm.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/snmpwalk.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/snmp.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/variables.5.gz
```

**net-snmp-libs**

```
Summary     : The NET-SNMP runtime libraries
Description : The net-snmp-libs package contains the runtime 
            : libraries for shared binaries and applications.
```

Files involved:

```
repoquery --list net-snmp-libs
/usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.20
/usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib/libnetsnmpagent.so.20
/usr/lib/libnetsnmpagent.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib/libnetsnmphelpers.so.20
/usr/lib/libnetsnmphelpers.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.so.20
/usr/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib/libnetsnmptrapd.so.20
/usr/lib/libnetsnmptrapd.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib/libsnmp.so.20
/usr/lib/libsnmp.so.20.0.0
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/ChangeLog.trimmed
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/README
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/TODO
/usr/share/snmp
/usr/share/snmp/mibs
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/AGENTX-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/BRIDGE-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-EVENT-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-SCRIPT-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/EtherLike-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HCNUM-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-ADDRESS-FAMILY-NUMBERS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-LANGUAGE-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-RTPROTO-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANAifType-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-INVERTED-STACK-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/INET-ADDRESS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IP-FORWARD-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-ICMP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-TCP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-UDP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/MTA-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RFC-1215.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RFC1155-SMI.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RFC1213-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SCTP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SMUX-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-MPD-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-PROXY-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-TARGET-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-USM-AES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-USM-DH-OBJECTS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-CONF.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-TM.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TCP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-IPFWACC-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UDP-MIB.txt
/var/lib/net-snmp
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.20
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmpagent.so.20
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmpagent.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmphelpers.so.20
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmphelpers.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmpmibs.so.20
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmpmibs.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmptrapd.so.20
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmptrapd.so.20.0.0
/usr/lib64/libsnmp.so.20
/usr/lib64/libsnmp.so.20.0.0
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/ChangeLog.trimmed
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/README
/usr/share/doc/net-snmp-libs-5.5/TODO
/usr/share/snmp
/usr/share/snmp/mibs
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/AGENTX-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/BRIDGE-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-EVENT-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-SCRIPT-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/EtherLike-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HCNUM-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-ADDRESS-FAMILY-NUMBERS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-LANGUAGE-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-RTPROTO-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANAifType-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-INVERTED-STACK-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/INET-ADDRESS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IP-FORWARD-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-ICMP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-TCP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPV6-UDP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/MTA-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RFC-1215.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RFC1155-SMI.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RFC1213-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SCTP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SMUX-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-MPD-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-PROXY-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-TARGET-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-USM-AES-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-USM-DH-OBJECTS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-CONF.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-TC.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-TM.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TCP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-IPFWACC-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UDP-MIB.txt
/var/lib/net-snmp
```