# issue with upgrading net-snmp5.5 to net-snmp5.7.3

Tags: shared-libraries, embedded-linux, net-snmp

I have to manage an Ethernet traffic card (my Linux target board(mips32)) having net-snmp 5.5  installed on it.

I want to upgrade it to latest net-snmp 5.7.3 and have successfully compiled net-snmp.

After that I had changed the all the `libnetsnmp*` library files, MIB text files and `snmpd` and `snmptrapd` daemons...but it gives errors like `failed to open shared library ....can not find libnesnmp.so.20 files` Why it is throwing this error even though I have updated net-snmp library files.

I am confused that what  files of 5.5 has to be replaced by the 5.7.3, in order to upgrade my net-snmp package.

Also please guide me the steps to install a Fresh net-snmp package on any Linux board.

Answer (score 0):

The net-snmp suite comes in 3 distinct Linux packages.

- `net-snmp` (the snmpd agent and snmptrapd daemons, documentation, etc)
- `net-snmp-utils` (various utilities e.g. for interrogating SNMP agents,
  sending traps, etc )
- `net-snmp-libs` (runtime libraries)

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32093525/449347 to a more detailed listing of files in each.

Make sure you have updated ALL that you have installed.

**EDIT ...**

Paraphrasing http://www.betweendots.com/topic/45-install-the-latest-version-of-net-snmp/

> When you have a CentOS box and type "yum install net-snmp", you'll get
>   version 5.5. If for some reason you want the latest version (5.7 at
>   the time of writing), then here's what you have to do:
>
> 1. `yum remove net-snmp net-snmp-utils`
> 2. Install dependencies: `yum install perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker`
> 3. Unpack and install net-snmp:
>
>    ```
>    tar zvxf net-snmp-*.tar.gz
>    cd net-snmp-*
>    ./configure
>    make
>    make install
>    ```
> 4. Create an `snmpd.conf` and put it in `/usr/local/share/snmp`.

But follow above link for more info!

Comment: Thanks man... I am concerned with NET-SNMP only
but my doubt persists that....

 why it throws error like "failed to open shared library ....can not find libnesnmp.so.20 files".... why it is throwing this error even though i have updated netsnmp library files.

Two points i want to discuss here
1. Is there any other file/files apart from mentioned above in my question that has to be changed?

2. what are the steps to install a new Fresh NET-SNMP package on a target board.

Comment: I had overcome  the error in opening the shared library by  creating sym link of all the net-snmp *.s0.30.0.3 file in /usr/lib by following way:--

ln -s /lib/libnesnmp.so.30.0.3 /usr/lib/libnesnmp.so.20 

But now i am getting Following Error

 netsnmp_get_table_handler(NULL) called
netsnmp_inject_handler() called illegally
NET-SNMP version 5.7.3 AgentX subagent connected
example-demon is up and running.


So why my NET-SNMP version 5.7.3 AgentX subagent connected???

Comment: Also I am able to send snmptraps on command line but not the snmpget/snmpset commands....

Can anyone figure out this problem?